# Are There Any Ways to Keep CreateML Training Model Up to Date?

Tags: json, swift, csv, coreml, createml

I'm a CoreML and CreateML newbie and have been playing around with CreateML for the past few days and started to wonder if there are any ways to keep the training model up to date without creating a new model with an updated csv model.

Is there a way to get a JSON file from online and train it?

I've tried  `let dataTable = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(string: "`the API in JSON format I am using`"))`

and it gave me an error: `"MLDataTable can only load from a file URL."`

The basic gist: Is there a way to train a model without having to download the updated version of the CSV or JSON file everyday?

Thanks :D